# Highchart solid gauge: trigger click on the grey area

Tags: highcharts

I use solid-gauge of highchart

I want to send callback to click event, not on the data area but on the grey area.

(You can see this sample for understand what I mean 'grey area'. https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid)

(I use version 4.1.7 - this is by customer design and I cannot change it, but let me know what is the options - I will 'convert' them to 4.1.7 options)

Thanks

Comment: In the [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.solidgauge.events.click) says the click event `fires when the series is clicked` - an alternative would be: set the gray area as another serie and then you could trigger the click in that area.

Answer (score 0):

You can add click event on a pane:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        events: {
            load: function() {
                this.pane[0].group.on('click', function() {
                    console.log('Clicked on pane!')
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e5muf7j1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#on